# more than one jquery isnt working

Tags: jquery

The following is the slideshow and jquery date code i am using on the website. Only one of them works, whichever is bellow the other works, please help with the problem. I am using php and html, it is a slideshow as the head and jquery date to pick up the date in the form

```
</style>
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.effect.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.effect-blind.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.effect-bounce.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.effect-clip.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.effect-drop.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.effect-fade.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.effect-fold.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.effect-scale.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.effect-slide.min.js"></script>
<script src="wb.slideshow.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $("#SlideShow1").slideshow(
   {
      interval: 14000,
      type: 'sequence',
      effect: 'fade',
      direction: '',
      effectlength: 4000
   });
});
</script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="Layer3" style="position:absolute;text-align:left;left:20%;top:0%;width:80%;height:40%;z-index:16;" title="">
   <div id="SlideShow1" style="position:absolute;left:0%;top:0%;width:99%;height:99%;z-index:0;">
      <img class="image" style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="images/outside4.jpg" alt="" title="">
      <img class="image" style="width:100%;height:100%;display:none;" src="images/outside3.jpg" alt="" title="">
      <img class="image" style="width:100%;height:100%;display:none;" src="images/reception2.jpg" alt="" title="">
      <img class="image" style="width:100%;height:100%;display:none;" src="images/restaurant3.jpg" alt="" title="">
   </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: you created different scopes. Just put datepicker code up after slide code ... doesnt that work for you?

Comment: You're including jQuery.js twice - you need to remove the second one.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Use this :

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.effect.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.effect-blind.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.effect-bounce.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.effect-clip.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.effect-drop.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.effect-fade.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.effect-fold.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.effect-scale.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.effect-slide.min.js"></script>
<script src="wb.slideshow.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $("#SlideShow1").slideshow(
   {
      interval: 14000,
      type: 'sequence',
      effect: 'fade',
      direction: '',
      effectlength: 4000
   });

    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker();
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="Layer3" style="position:absolute;text-align:left;left:20%;top:0%;width:80%;height:40%;z-index:16;" title="">
   <div id="SlideShow1" style="position:absolute;left:0%;top:0%;width:99%;height:99%;z-index:0;">
      <img class="image" style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="images/outside4.jpg" alt="" title="">
      <img class="image" style="width:100%;height:100%;display:none;" src="images/outside3.jpg" alt="" title="">
      <img class="image" style="width:100%;height:100%;display:none;" src="images/reception2.jpg" alt="" title="">
      <img class="image" style="width:100%;height:100%;display:none;" src="images/restaurant3.jpg" alt="" title="">
   </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: I can see what you've done, but for the sake of anyone that might not, what have you actually done here? How does your answer differ from the question, what have you added, removed or changed and why does it fix the problem?

Comment: Downvoted for all of the reasons MLeFevre stated. "Use this:" and a code dump is not a useful answer for anybody who is actually interested in learning.

Comment: Changes i made are very simple so i dont think so that it need any explanation , ( I am new to stack overflow and trying to answer as quick as  possible , ll consider your point in future . Thanks )

Comment: I don't think Stack Overflow is about quantity, but quality. As MLeFevre and Anthony Grist said: please try to explain *why* you changed something, what it solves etc.

Comment: @parveen You're not that new to SO (1 year, 7 months). Anyway, the changes you've made are simple, but they're still worth pointing out. The person who asked the question/anyone in the future who might read this answer may not be at your level, and a single sentence explaining what was wrong would help them, surely it's worth adding just for clarity?

Comment: @Smit , Thanks a lot mate :)  , you saved me ... finally my purpose to help you is completed.